# Login redirect on ASP.NET Core application with external login

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-authentication

I have an ASP.NET Core web application and I am decorating a few controller action methods with Authorize attribute.

So, when I am not logged in, it doesn't do any redirect and only shows me a blank page for that controller action. I have gone through a couple of tutorials and they talk about Cookie authentication.

So, I made changes in my Startup.cs and added the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookie",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
    AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Forbidden/"),
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

I also made a change in Authorize attribute to include ActiveAuthenticationScheme as:

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = "Cookie")]
```

Now when I tried to go to that controller action, I get the login page. I am able to login successfully but I am again redirected to Login page instead of showing the controller action method View.

I can tell that I successfully logged in as I can see my email and a 'logoff' button on top of page (Layout with partial view). It seems like I am authenticated but Not Authorized. It that is true that I should have seen the forbidden page but I am seeing only the login page.

Am I missing something here? Why I am being redirected to Login page even after logging in?

.

Comment: I haven't made any changes in the Login action that comes standard with a new ASP.NET Core application with Individual User Authentication.

Comment: Is it really redirecting to the login page after login, or is it just refreshing the view?  The default asp.net core template (last I checked) should have a parameter in the Login action for a url redirect.  That's what they are using to go back to the original page.

Comment: It is going to login action post method and it's going into result.Succeeded (so, the login is successful) and the returnUrl is my controller/action where I wanted to go. But then it just goes back to Login again. So, basically, it wants to go to the returnUrl, but somehow, it's not authorized (I have Authorize attribute on the action where I want to go).

Comment: What does your configuration look like in your startup?

Comment: I have changed my configuration several times since then but nothing seem to work. I've now deleted UseCookieAuthentication from Startup and also removed the ActiveAuthenticationSchemes from Authorize attribute. So, I am getting a blank screen when user not logged in. I'll restart this authorization procedure but before that I am facing some other hosting related issues that I need to fix. If you have any suggestion please let me know.